# Getting URL from Mac App

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, interface-builder

What would I put into an IBAction to get a URL (email, or HTTP) that opens a browser?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open page in Safari:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: @"http://www.google.com/"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]
```

Create new message within Mail:

```
NSString *subject = @"The subject";
NSString *body = @"The message";
NSString *address = @"mail@address.com";
NSString *cc = @"mail@address.com";
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:%@?cc=%@&subject=%@&body=%@", address, cc, subject, body];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: The new mail message is throwing a 'UIApplication Undeclared' error. I copied and pasted that code into the .m file. Any help? I declared by IBAction..

Comment: @Zakman411: I changed the code a litte, now it should work :)

Comment: Thanks! :) Also, I had to change the UIApplication in the URL openURL snippet (actually, both snippets have UIApplication) to NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace. It kept saying undeclared :/ But it works now thanks for your help!

Comment: @Zakman411: Oops, you are right, the code i mentioned above is for the iPhone. I'm happy it worked with `[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]`. Sorry for my confusion!